# How to release an app at certain time?

Tags: android, google-play

On iOS, we can send an app for approval without going live. After approval, the app will be in status **"Pending Developer Release"**. Later, the developer can press the button **"Release This Version"** and make it public almost instantly. The app can be in this state for days.

I need something like this for an android app on Google Play.

The app is currently in Beta. I am using the new **"Manage Releases"** Page. I can create a release and pick the Beta build, but there is no way to specify the actual going live process of this release. The next step is **"Rollout"**, which as far as I can tell will make the app public immediately.

In addition, there used to be a way to schedule a release (actual date), which is not there anymore in the new "Manage Releases". **"Timed publishing"** drop down is there, but seems to do nothing (there is no place to actually pick a date and time). Did google remove those features, or am I missing something (hopefully I am).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send the app and, once approved, publish it whenever you want.

You can follow the guide [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334282?hl=en) in the "Publish an app update" > "Publish with timed publishing" section.

I don't think it works for new apps, but it may work in your case as you already have a beta published (I'm curious to know if that's the case, please let me know in the comments)

Comment: Marking this as the right answer, since this is the best documentation from google. Ironic that you have to go to stack overflow to find a page in a website written by the biggest search company.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't look like there is an option for new apps even with something in beta. The only option I have is "Start Rollout to Production"

Comment: @JenniferP. - could you confirm with beta published, timed publishing works for new apps?